# Angular 2 CLI App throwing 404 errors once deployed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I recently updated an app I've been working on to latest version of Angular CLI (currently beta25).  Using ng serve all routing works perfectly locally.

I then use ng build --prod, zip up the dist directory and load it to my web server (currently hosted on AWS Tomcat).  When I navigate index.html, I'm using a default route to drop into a "home" component.  Everything works to that point.  If I refresh the browser, however, I get a 404.  Additionally any direct and deep link navigation I attempt to other views in the app throw 404 as well (Here is my app.routing.ts for reference)

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SolutionComponent } from './solution/solution.component';
import { AssetComponent } from './asset/asset.component';
import { PropertyComponent } from './property/property.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path: 'solution',
    component: SolutionComponent
},
{
    path: 'asset',
    component: AssetComponent
},
{
    path: 'asset/:solutionId',
    component: AssetComponent
},
{
    path: 'property/:solutionId',
    component: PropertyComponent
},  
{
    path: 'property',
    component: PropertyComponent
},      
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',        
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
];
```

I've read in other posts that this may be related to PathLocationStrategy, and [one in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018765/deploy-angular-2-app-with-webpack-to-tomcat-404-errors) indicated that I needed to adjust my base href as follows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="./">
```

I've tried deploying versions of the app with and without the dot and the issue still persists.  I'm kind of stumped.  I read about folks having similar issues but haven't found a good solution documented.  I'm hopeful that someone in the Angular 2 community might help shed some light on what's happening and give me an idea on how to move forward.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1/15/2017:
In case it's helpful for anyone, I wanted to circle back and highlight a couple of things I had to do to deploy my "finished" Angular2 CLI application to a hosted environment.

First, to turn on the Rewrite Valve on Apache Tomcat8 on AWS (pretty standard hosting option) I had to use the ElasticBeanstalk ebextensions feature in order to swap in a context.xml file with the Tomcat rewrite valve enabled.  The **server-update.config** file looked like this for me:

```
container_commands: 
  replace-config: 
    command: cp .ebextensions/context.xml /etc/tomcat8/context.xml
```

Second, the url rewrite itself.  there may be a more elegant way to do this that hasn't occurred to me yet, but my **rewrite.config** currently looks like this:

```
# match requests for basic resource files and pass them through without substitution
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.(css|js|jpg|png|ico|woff2|woff|ttf).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

# app-specific rules
# match app routes and redirect to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/home.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/solution.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/asset.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/property.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: You need to configure url rewrite on your server, saw a post a day or so ago, can't find it.

Comment: just   <base href="/"> without the . and if you have your app in a folder where you build it try somthing like   <base href="/index.html"> or   <base href="/app_build/">

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519810/refresh-page-got-404-only-happen-when-using-dist-folder/41523241#41523241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Html5 pushstate support on your web server.

This is very trivial for nginx, Apache and IIS,  as well as other web servers.

This is done through a set of rewrite rules that implement the following conditions:

- if the request is for file that exists, return it
- otherwise return the index.html

A Google search for instructions on your specific web server should get you started.

Comment: It took me a while to verify your instructions because I was travelling, but finally got the url re-writing working on Apache this morning.

I do see a little weirdness in that navigating back to a previous page requires two clicks of the back button, but I can live with that for now I suppose.  At least my app is serving correctly. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @rswillis can you please elaborate what are the changes you done for this issue. ..I am getting same issue in apache server.